# Random values returned in mysql

Tags: mysql, random, range

i'm having some issues working with mysql, in a particular case, i'm getting random values in a query

```
  select t.rango AS "Rango de Precios", AVG(comentarios.puntos) as Promedio
from
    comentarios RIGHT JOIN juegos ON(comentarios.id_juego = juegos.id_juegos),
   (select case
       when precio = 0 then 'Gratis'
       when precio > 0 and precio < 300 then 'De 0 a 300'
       when precio > 300 and precio < 600 then 'De 300 a 600'
    else 'Mayor a 600'
       end
       as rango,
       precio
       from juegos) as t  
group by rango
```

I hope you can help me!

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I'm trying to get an average of points for each category (if precio is = 0, between 0 and 300, etc)

The problem is i'm getting random values of avg(comentarios.puntos)

I tried to do the query like this

[Table juegos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrU39.jpg)

[Table comentarios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnhsF.jpg)

I'm getting as response

```
Rango de Precios      Promedio
De 0 a 300            7.6667
De 300 a 600          7.6667
Gratis                7.6667
Mayor a 600           7.6667
```

I hope you can help me! thanks so much!

EDIT: I solved using the case without a subquery

```
SELECT (
CASE
when precio = 0 THEN ' 0$'
when precio between 0 and 300 then 'Entre 0$ y 300$'
when precio between 300 and 600 then 'Entre 300$ y 600$'
else 'Más de 600$'
end) as Rango,
AVG(comentarios.puntos) as 'Puntaje Promedio'

from juegos left join comentarios on(juegos.id_juegos =      comentarios.id_juego)
group by Rango
```

Thank you guys!

Comment: Random values like, 9, 10, 8, 7 when in the tables that values doesn't exist

Comment: There's not enough information to diagnose the problem. Please include table structures, sample data, expected output, and explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: Well just by looking to your SQL I know for a fact that there are something wrong. First because you are making a cartesian product, most probably is the reason you are getting the "random" values. You are multipling all the results of your right join with that subquery. You either joined the tables wrong or you missed a JOIN/LEFT LOIN/RIGHT JOIN with that subquery.

Comment: I edited the post adding more information! Ty so much!